# What is the bound of coefficients of the series $e^t$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'd like to get a bound of the coefficients of the series:

$$e^t = 1 + \frac{t^1}{1!} + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{t^n}{n!} + \dots$$

In other words, after $n$ terms we get a term

$$\frac{t^n}{n!} < c \text{ for some } c$$

I'd like to get a formula (or approximation) of $n$ in terms of $c$ and $t$ or vice versa.  What is this formula?

We can assume that we have real $t$ such that $|t|<d$ for some $d$.

Comment: When you say "or vice versa," you could simply say that:
$$t^nc\gt \frac{t^n}{n!}\implies c\gt \frac{1}{n!}$$
(I'm having a little difficulty seeing what you're asking)

Comment: But isn't the expression $t^n/n!$ exact already? So given $c$, you can find $n$ and $t$ such that $t^n/n! < c$.

Comment: I'm thinking that stirling's approximation will help...

Comment: for large $t$, the terms will first increase then decrease, and the $n$ at which the biggest term occurs tends to increase as $t$ grows. so there's no bound that will work for all possible values of $t$

Comment: @suissidle: I'm trying to find a bound for a given $t$, such that for real $t$, $|t| < d$ for some $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's approximation $\ln n! \approx n (\ln n -1)$ yields a reasonable rough bound on $n$. The inequality $|t|^n/n!<c$ is equivalent to $\ln n!> \ln(c^{-1})+n\ln |t|$. With Stirling's approximation this is $n\ln n> \ln(c^{-1})+n\ln(e|t|)$.  Inequality $n\ln n> \ln(c^{-1})$ is approximately $n>\ln(c^{-1})/\ln\ln (c^{-1})$, while $n\ln n>n\ln(e|t|)$ amounts to $n>e|t|$. So, 
$$n\approx e|t|+ \frac{\ln(c^{-1})}{\ln\ln (c^{-1})} \tag1$$
Derived in such a sloppy way, the formula (1) can't be expected to be very precise. But it's a decent estimate.

Test case: with $t=5$ and $c=10^{-9}$, formula (1) gives $n\approx 20.4$. The value of $5^n/n!$ is $1.4\cdot 10^{-9}$ when $n=20$ and $2\cdot 10^{-10}$ when $n=21$. Bingo!